# c# sort datetime list get the latest time

Tags: c#

In C# how to get the latest time?

My list:

```
2019-12-11 8:00:00
2019-11-11 9:00:00
```

the output should be:

```
2019-11-11 9:00:00
2019-12-11 8:00:00
```

`mylist.Last()` is  `2019-12-11 8:00:00`

Comment: Sort: `myList.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));` Biggest value: `var max = myList.Max(item => item);`

Comment: Just `myList.Max()` should work, no?

Comment: O(N Log N) solutions to an O(N) problem hurt me.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - how is this `O(1)`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I meant  O(N Log N) vs O(N)...

Comment: @MatthewWatson Note that .NET Core now optimizes for this case, and `OrderBy(...).First()` and `.Last()` are O(n). `Max()` has always been O(n) of course.

Comment: @canton7 - How is `.OrderBy` `O(n)`?

Comment: @canton7 Interesting, I didn't know that!

Comment: @Enigmativity `.OrderBy` just on its own doesn't do anything (even in Framework, sorting only happens when the result is actually enumerated). But it returns a special object. If you then call `.First()` or `.Last()` on that object, it hits a special code path that just fetches the mix/max item (as appropriate). [See here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs,77) and similar.

Comment: @canton7 I found some documentation about that new optimisation, if anyone is interested: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/2401

Comment: @canton7 - It doesn't seem to do that in c# 7.2.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's on .NET Core - nothing to do with the C# language version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use linq to achieve this. Use OrderBy or OrderByDesc to sort your list and Last or LastOrDefault to take the last value.

```
var list = new List<DateTime>();
list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
var result = list.LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `OrderBy`returns a new `IEnumerable<DateTime>` - it doesn't mutate the underlying list. However your code does not do anything with the return value from `OrderBy`.

Comment: You can achieve that by setting the return value from the orderBy to the variable list. I will edit the answer

Comment: Can you fix `list.LastOrDefault();` while you're at it?